# GET request in python with "requests" lib to a CloudFlare protected site returns Error 1020 "Please enable cookies"

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I'm making a request like this:

```py
import requests

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get('http://<endpoint-url>')

print(r.text)
```

It returns an HTML page, and I can see these lines:

```html
Please enable cookies.</div>
...
<span data-translate="error">Error</span>
<span>1020</span>
```

When I print `s.cookies.get_dict()` I'm getting this:

```js
{'__cfduid': 'd06702291bb6520f2 ...'}
```

It works when I open the URL in the browser and I can see it sets this cookie. The problem is when I try to make the request from python.

I looked in the response library docs, doesn't mention how to "enable cookies". Couldn't find anything useful on error 1020, or in the target website's API docs. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Login to your cloudflare account under security tab --> overview --> select apply filter search with rayid, you can search reason by expanding rayid. Unblock the ipaddress.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev6i7.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).